# VBA excel make read only a text file

Tags: excel, vba, readonly, opentext

Is it possible to open a text file as **readOnly** with the **workbooks.opentext** method?
When I try to run a macro while the file is opened by an other user I get the message "file in use".

There is no **readOnly** option avalaible in the **Opentext** expression;

*OpenText( Filename , Origin , StartRow , DataType , TextQualifier , ConsecutiveDelimiter , Tab , Semicolon , Comma , Space , Other , OtherChar , FieldInfo , TextVisualLayout , DecimalSeparator , ThousandsSeparator , TrailingMinusNumbers , Local )*

Meanwhile there is a **ReadOnly** option available with the Worbooks.Open method.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Workbooks.OpenText` use `Workbooks.Open`